# CPU Power Saving Setting for Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure-vm

I'm seeing from Perfmon that %C2 Time is being primarily used instead of %C1 Time in our Azure VM that is used for SQL Server. Normally if the host was on something like VMWare, I could get the Admins to change the Power setting from Balanced to High Performance within the Hosts BIOS.

Does anyone know if this can be done or even if this Processor State Transition time is a concern on the Azure environments?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like IaaS, did you check the Windows power setting?

Comment: Hi Sean,

Thanks for the response. Yes it is IAAS. The Windows Power Setting is showing as High Performance. But from looking at the perfmon metric, it looks like the host is set to power saving. Just a gut feeling. Just wondering How I would know this?

Comment: You won't as you'll have no access to the underlying host. If you *believe* this to be the case, open an azure support ticket.

Comment: Thanks Sean, passed my findings over to the Azure Admin Team here.